# Can I provide an implementation of MembersInjector<T> with Dagger 2?

Tags: dagger-2

I am trying to replace Guice with Dagger-2. Everything is looking good so far, but there is one thing I can't find an idiomatic solution for.

Let's say I have a class that I cannot extend and have no control over the code. Additionally I am not able to create instances of the class. The instances will be created - but not initialized - by another framework. I stumbled over the `MembersInjector<T>` interface, but it seems to handle only classes with annotations. I am looking for a way to provide an implementation of `MemebersInjector<Type>` (see example code below).

```
final class Type {
  A a;
  B b;

  public Type() {
  }

  public void initialize(A a, B b) {this.a=a; this.b=b};
}
```

My component and modules can provide `A` and `B`.

What I am looking for is something like

```
@Component(modules = MyModule.class)
interface MyComponent {
  Type inject(Type t);
}
```

or

```
@Component(modules = MyModule.class)
interface MyComponent {
  MembersInjector<Type> getTypeInjector();
}
```

and a way to provide my own implementation of the `MembersInjector`.

I tried something like this

```
@Module
class MyModule {
  @Provides
  MembersInjector<Type> provideTypeInjector(A a, B b) {
    return instance -> {
      instance.initialize(a, b);
    }
  }
}
```

but Dagger-2 ist not happy with that.

Any idea how to make this work?

Comment: Why not initialize it in an `@Provides` annotated method in your module?

Comment: My bad. I forgot to mention, that I am not able to create the instance of class Type. The instance of Type will be given to me. I just have to initialize it and want to use Dagger for doing it. I will edit my original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's an idiomatic way to do this other than creating your own POJO, and that's probably fine.

The value of a @Component's `inject(T)` method or `MembersInjector<T>` instance is that it is *how you request an object that Dagger writes based on `T`'s `@Inject` annotations*. If Dagger isn't scanning the class and generating the object for you, then you'll be responsible for populating the object anyway, so you might as well write your own initializer.

```
class YourTypeInitializer { // nothing to extend or implement
  private final Provider<A> aProvider;
  private final Provider<B> bProvider;

  @Inject YourTypeInitializer(Provider<A> aProvider, Provider<B> bProvider) {
    this.aProvider = aProvider;
    this.bProvider = bProvider;
  }

  public YourType inject(YourType instance) {
    instance.initialize(aProvider.get(), bProvider.get());
    return instance;  // for convenience
  }
}
```

or with field injection:

```
class YourTypeInitializer {
  @Inject Provider<A> aProvider;
  @Inject Provider<B> bProvider;
  @Inject YourTypeInitializer() {}

  public YourType inject(YourType instance) {
    instance.initialize(aProvider.get(), bProvider.get());
    return instance;  // for convenience
  }
}
```

Then, rather than injecting `MembersInjector<YourType>`, just inject `YourTypeInitializer`; rather than calling `yourComponent.inject(yourTypeInstance)`, just call `yourComponent.getYourTypeInitializer().inject(yourTypeInstance)`. It's a bit of boilerplate, but without `@Inject` annotations there's very little Dagger can do for you as an alternative.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation and the code examples. That is exactly the way I did it before asking myself: "there must be a better way". What I still do not understand is, when dagger does not know how to create an object, you can tell dagger the how using modules. Why not the same with injection? Writing a method in a module that returns a MembersInjector and then dagger can use that method to generate the inject method of the component. Much less boilerplate. Maybe a feature request?

Comment: I posted a feature request ( [link](https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/1046) )

Comment: You're welcome to a feature request, to Dagger or to more-appropriate sister project [Google Auto](https://github.com/google/auto/blob/master/README.md), but think first: _What description would be readable and type-safe here?_ You'd need to list out the should-be-`@Inject` fields and methods in a reflective way, ideally using annotations so Dagger can generate an implementation at compile time. Even in Java 8 syntax, Java doesn't make this easy, and strings break some of Dagger's refactoring tool support. Hopefully in most cases you can just use `@Provides` or one-off POJOs.